# how to stop Clementine playback on suspend using systemd

Tags: fedora, systemd, suspend

I'm trying to stop Clementine playback using DBus before entering suspend mode. Here is my service file right now:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop Clementine playback before suspend
Requires=dbus.service
Before=sleep.target
Before=dbus.service

[Service]
User=jo
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=-/bin/sh -c 'qdbus org.mpris.clementine /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Stop'

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Now, this works, i.e. playback is stopped. However, systemd then proceeds to take a long time to actually enter suspend mode. Looking at the logs in journalctl, I see:

```
Jun 05 23:43:53 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jun 05 23:44:18 localhost.localdomain systemd-sleep[7052]: Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply
Jun 05 23:44:18 localhost.localdomain systemd-sleep[7052]: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the 
Jun 05 23:44:18 localhost.localdomain systemd-sleep[7052]: Suspending system...
```

My first thought is that the DBus system, or maybe Clementine itself is suspended before it has time to reply, thus causing a hang. This is why I tried adding a dependency to the dbus service in my service file above. However, that does not do the trick.

Any ideas?